# How to separate background from foreground images in opencv

Tags: opencv

How can I separate the background from the objects in foreground for an image using opencv?

Comment: [How can you ask a question properly in order to get answers?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Background subtraction

Using [GPU](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/nonfree/doc/background_subtraction.html),
[Java](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractor.html)

[Here](http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189) is a tutorial on background detection, I suggest you follow that.

Also, I agree with Rakkun, Tag your questions and detail them better for more helpful answers. Read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: but he asked for separating 'an image'